# cURL Scraping Wrong Webpage

Tags: macos, curl, cookies, web-scraping

I am attempting to scrape a webpage that requires a login using `curl` in the Mac Terminal but can't seem to get it right. I have a `cookies.txt` file with my login info that I am reading into the command, but I can't get it to scrape the intended page. When I run

`curl -b /Users/dwm8/Desktop/cookies.txt -o /Users/dwm8/Desktop/file.txt https://kenpom.com/team.php?team=Duke&y=2002`

the contents of `file.txt` are the webpage data from https://kenpom.com/team.php?team=Duke instead of https://kenpom.com/team.php?team=Duke&y=2002. Is there a fix for this? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` is a shell metacharacter that separates commands and indicates the command before it should be run in the background. So, your command:

```
curl ... https://kenpom.com/team.php?team=Duke&y=2002
```

gets parsed as two separate commands:

```
curl ... https://kenpom.com/team.php?team=Duke &    # The & means run curl in the background
y=2002    # This just sets a shell variable
```

In order to get the shell to treat `&` as part of the argument to `curl` rather than a command separator, you need to quote it (either single- or double-quotes would work) or escape it with a backslash:

```
curl ... 'https://kenpom.com/team.php?team=Duke&y=2002'
curl ... "https://kenpom.com/team.php?team=Duke&y=2002"
curl ... https://kenpom.com/team.php\?team=Duke\&y=2002
```

Oh, and notice that I also escaped the `?` in that last example? That's because `?` is also a shell metacharacter (specifically, a wildcard). In this case it probably wouldn't cause any trouble, but it's safest to quote or escape it just in case. And since it's hard to keep track of exactly which characters can cause trouble, I'll recommend quoting instead of escaping, and just quoting everything that you're at all unsure about.

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciate you dumbing it down for me, this is a huge help

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap url part in quotes.